# mysql error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '192.168.250.99'

Tags: mysql, authentication

while trying to login to mysql , getting error:

```
**[root@kics ]# mysql -u<user> -p<password> <dbName>
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '192.168.250.99' (2)**
```

i searched over internet , but only getting answers for

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

actually 192.168.250.99 is my own machine ip., when i use
 `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u<user> -p<password> <dbName>` , its getting logged in but not with `mysql -u<user> -p<password> <dbName>`

As its enterprise application , i cant post my.cnf. kindly tell me value of which field i can provide

After restarting machine , i am able to log in . But i need to restart it every time , then doing some operations on application , i am facing such issues again and again

```
[root@krishna etc]# /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'pwd'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '192.168.250.99' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '192.168.250.99' exists!
```

Kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: post your config, your mysql-client is trying to connect to a remote mysql installation rather then your local one. Is this what you intend it to do?

Comment: Is there a MySQL server (which is running) on `192.168.250.99`?

Comment: Post your `/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

At a guess you've put the IP address of your machine in my.cnf where you should have provided the filesystem socket path:

socket=192.168.250.99

(above is nonsense). Should be something like....

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

(and I'm failing to see why you can't post your my.conf file for an enterprise application)

If the my.cnf file is indeed wrong, then your error log should have had lots of warnings in there - why didn't you know that already if this is an enterprise application?

Comment: its socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock only in my.cnf .Actually i start facing this issue recently. After doing some db operations via GUI, i get such error

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your server to that specific IP address

 So add this to your `my.cnf` under `[mysqld]`

```
bind-address=192.168.250.99
```

or write

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

for all ip addresses

Comment: did , but not able to log in.

Comment: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--socket=192.168.250.99'
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '192.168.250.99' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
 why i am getting this issue while i am running as root. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution. Actually i was executing

```
[root@kics ]# mysql -u<user> -p<password> <dbName>
```

from root , thats why i was getting this error. when i logged in as krishna (admin profile),
and executed the same command , i successfully got logged.

```
[krishna@krishna ~]$ mysql -uroot -p<password> ;
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.10-enterprise-commercial-advanced MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

still i dont know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysql` client is apparently trying to connect to MySQL through a socket whose default location is misconfigured. It must be loading a configuration file from some unexpected location.

[This manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) lists the locations where a configuration file is searched for. On Linux, possible locations are:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
~/.mylogin.cnf
```

When you find the actual file, look for the `socket` clause in the `client` or `mysql` section. Replace this line with `host=[your IP here or 127.0.0.1]`, or provide the `socket` clause with the actual socket location (path).